# Problems with adding flutter to my PATH in ubuntu

Tags: linux, flutter, path

I tried installing Android Studio and Flutter on the PC. I followed some tutorials for the paths and I did a great many things. I am rather confused how many completely different approaches there are editing different files and commands to change the path permanently. I got it to work in theory even, if I enter echo `$PATH` I get

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:home/dev/flutter/bin:/snap/bin
```

Now, i do not know if I put the path in correctly, but it is the path that correctly leads to my flutter bin folder. I am not sure if I am supposed to crop it or anything. If i open a terminal in this directory, and enter 'flutter' i get 'flutter: command not found', while ./flutter or ./flutter doctor do what i would like to happen in any terminal but also without the ./

So, apparently flutter is installed and works, but the path is what is giving me the biggest headache. Any ideas what i could have done wrong? I really tried everything the dart docs told me to do and followed many other tutorials to no avail.

Comment: Make sure you follow this: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux and really follow this: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#update-your-path

Comment: Hey there @Benjamin, this is the first thing i did, i knew with windows it was very easy to just add it to the others, but with linux after many hours i did not get it to work properly for some reason.